# php proxy problem

Tags: php, proxy, web, webfilter

i used [php web proxy](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/) for limit web access in a office, clients have not internet access, so they use this php web proxy to view web page.
the php proxy is running on a computer that have access to internet via a squid proxy server. ( for example i deny access to www.yahoo.com in squid ). all ok.
So,if any clients send request to php proxy for yahoo.com it will be denied. ok.

**But, if client open google via php proxy and search for yahoo , it shows yahoo.com at first result. then client click on result link and it will show yahoo.com website for client.
how to control access in this way?**

Comment: Proxying a proxy? Redundant redundancies... You couldn't prevent people from using Google's caches to surf another site, unless you block access to Google itself.

Comment: also blocking google is simplest way to solve. but google cache is not problem! the problem is url encoding by php proxy. (it is not proxying proxy. php web proxy just get the web site and show it for user, not access control, no filtering!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B remarked, I think you have some issues in your current setup - for example you could allow your clients to connect directly to squid, and achieve much the same result (unless I am missing something truly fundamental in your setup).

Seems to me like you want a proper web filter though. What your trying to do is vaguely possible in a DIY method, but much easier and generally more cost effective with a web filter product. I work for [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.net) so I will, with a hint of bias, recommend our filter, but in the interests of fairness, Barracuda is inexpensive, and there's also the likes of Websense available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this particular php web proxy has some serious design issues, if people can select a result in a list of searches and go to a site that they weren't allowed to.  What package is it?